# How to alert when last cat show full image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, responsive

How to alert when last cat show full image ?

When you click `Click HERE` cat image will slide, i want to apply my code for alert when display last cat full image (in this cast when click 3 time)

But please do not to count click. because i have to use in difference screen size.

https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/5/

```
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" id="move-left" onclick="left_fn(-222)">
        Click HERE
    </div>


    <div style=" width: 455px; overflow: hidden; ">
        <ul style=" width: 2000em; transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); margin-left: -10px; padding: 0;" id="cat-ul">
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Wc9bszd.jpg">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<script>
function left_fn(value) {
    document.getElementById("cat-ul").style.transform = "translate3d("+value+"px, 0px, 0px)";
    var x = (value + 222);
    var y = (value - 222);
    document.getElementById('move-left').setAttribute('onclick','left_fn('+y+')')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use jQuery and Viewport-plugin. The plugin ads couple of new pseudo selectors. For example you can check any element is inside or outside of viewport. A little snippet:

```
if($("#lastChild").is(":in-viewport"))
{
  alert("hhh");
}
```

See here for more informations: https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

I've edited a working fiddle with the viewport plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/manumanfred/vncxfx0s/8/

Comment: Could you please give me some fiddle.

Comment: an click event is triggered immediately with an duration of 0, it doesn't have a callback function. Just add a timeout of 1ms or more: [https://jsfiddle.net/manumanfred/vncxfx0s/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/manumanfred/vncxfx0s/10/)

Comment: i have some error on my server `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: in-viewport jquery.min.js:2`

Comment: do you have include the viewport plugin? Link is in my first post^^